# PHP - Files run only for one day on server

Tags: php, hosting, cpanel

I have few php web services created on my server. They were created yesterday. They will run only for one day. Then again i have make a new file with same name and code. It again executes for a day, and same process i have to repeat. Whats the problem ? Please help resolve. 
Hosting provider says they have no idea of the issue.

Comment: You'll need to post some parts of your code.

Comment: and explain a bit of "*They will run only for one day. Then again i have make a new file with same name and code.*"

Comment: This sounds more like a server configuration issue, not a programming problem. There's something reverting your server from a backup every day, wiping out your changes.

Comment: @BagusTesa These php files are called from an webhook from a Saas Application. So they post data to the database. They execute only for one day. Then again i have recreate them with same name and they work fine.
Files have 644 permissions